# Как изменить страницу просмотра заказа в админке, не трогая изначальный файл?

Tags: битрикс

Как изменить страницу просмотра заказа в админке, не трогая изначальный файл? Она находится на странице bitrix/admin/sale_order_view.php?ID=123

Например, что-то вроде изменения шаблонов компонентов bitrix через local/templates/shop/components/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый правильный вариант, повесить изменения на события `OnAdminSaleOrderEdit`, `OnAdminSaleOrderView`, `OnAdminSaleOrderView`, в зависимости от того, что нужно изменить и как.

Добавлю небольшой пример, если вне какого-то своего модуля, то в `init.php` регистрируем обработчик на событие:

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnAdminSaleOrderView', 'OnAdminSaleOrderView');

function OnAdminSaleOrderView() {
   // обработка, тут уже почитать в статьях, что и как правильно делать
}
```